# How to define dependency in package.json for gitrepository?

Tags: node.js, git, npm-install, package.json

In my reactjs project I have a dependency on a module that is in another gitrepo(stash) so I created this in my package.json as a property of dependencies :

```
"somemodule":{
  "name": "somemodule",
  "dependencies": {
    "private-repo": "https://link_to_the_other_repo"
  }
}
```

This repo contains a minified version and non minified version of the same file. When I run npm install the module does not get installed, there is no error message either. How can I create this dependency?
I have managed to get the dist/minified version of the file from the other repo. How can I refer to this in my package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a private git module:

If you have RSA key added to your machine(secure & recommended):

```
"dependencies": {
    "package-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com/project/repo.git"
}
```

If you want https:

```
"dependencies": {
        "package-name": "git+https://username:password@github.com/project/repo.git"
}
```

Its not recommended to store username, password in your `package.json` file, so better add ssh keygen to your machine and use the first one.

Comment: Just in case I need to authenticate what do I do?

Comment: I cannot get it to work for now but I have the dist file from the other repo. How can I refer to this in my package.json?